# How to add a default env var to all docker containers

Tags: docker

I am trying to configure my dockerd to inject an env var into all containers that it starts.

More specifically, I need every container to use SSH for it's `DOCKER_HOST` and also where that host is, so that containers don't try to volume mount the docker unix socket with `-v /var/docker/docker.sock:/var/sock/docker.sock` because that's a command that needs to be restricted

So, the general question (inject ANY env var to all containers) would be useful, but specifically, I need to inject the DOCKER_HOST, which might have a non generalized answer

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge there is no native facility for injecting a set of default environment variables into all Docker containers; see [Moby issue #16699](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/16699) for some thoughts on exactly this question.

I guess if you were really ambitious, you could write a mutating proxy that sits in front of the docker socket and have it intercept the [`ContainerCreate`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.43/#tag/Container/operation/ContainerCreate) operation, Update the `Env` key, and pass the request on to Docker.

Comment: That moby issue is closed because they added a specific feature for http_proxy (which was OP original intent). They never seem to have addressed the larger issue